# JacksonXML simple list of Strings serialization and desirialization

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have this xml

```
<DeviceSettings>
        <Messages>
            <Message>1</Message>
            <Message>2</Message>
            <Message>3</Message>
        </Messages>
</DeviceSettings>
```

My Kotlin data classes:

```
data class DeviceSettings(
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Messages")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Messages")
    val  messages: List<String>
)
```

This looks like its working ok but I really dont understand why when serilizing back the object it becomes like this

```
<DeviceSettings>
<Messages>
<Messages>1</Messages>
<Messages>2</Messages>
<Messages>3</Messages>
</Messages>
</DeviceSettings>
```

I would also like to have this structure:

```
data class DeviceSettings(
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Messages")
    val  messages: List<Message>
)

data class Message(
    val value: String,
)
```

But the above trows an error about wrong type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved via

```
data class DeviceConfig(
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Messages")
    val  messages: Messages
)

data class Messages(
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Messages" ,useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Message")
    val messages: List<String>
)
```